# CakePHP : find data on multi model

Tags: cakephp, model

I have a table products with several associations
example :

[image: Schema]

and i want to use on view all data about a products with conditions

This is the Product model :

```
<?php
  class Product extends Model {
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Label','PircingScale');
    public $hasMany = array('LabelR','PircingScaleR');
  }
```

And the label model :

```
<?php
  class Label extends Model {
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Product');
   }
```

And the relation model :

```
<?php
    class LabelR extends Model {
       public $useTable = 'labels_products';
       public $belongsTo = array('Product','Label');
    }
```

And the same with pircing_scale model

Now i make a find on an index controller :

```
<?php
 class IndexController extends AppController {
      public $uses = array('Product','Label','PircingScale');

      public function index() {      
         $this->set('lastNewProduct', $this->Product->LabelR->find('all', array(
           'conditions' => array('Label.id' => 1),
           'limit' => 3,
         )));
      }
}
```

And in my view i want to display the information in pircing_scale about all products

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far

Comment: There are many answers for that short question. Please specify your question.

Comment: Sorry, i have edit my answer

Comment: No, i want to find all products by label and with this result display all information about this product (for my example the pircing scale)

Answer (score 0):

### Use containable

The [Containable behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) is a core behavior designed to allow you to define the scope of find results.

To use it just add it to the model you will query, or the AppModel to be able to use it with any model.

Then your find call would look something like this:

```
$this->Product->LabelR->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Label',
        'Product' => array(
            'PircingScale'
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => array('Label.id' => 1),
    'limit' => 3,
 ));
```